# Google Sheet Script: resetting active cell with getActiveSheet()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to copy a range of values from a sheet (Test1) and paste them into the active cell of the next sheet (Test2).

The problem I am having is that the active cell keeps getting reset back to A1 instead the last cell I clicked on that page.

When I run the script from the second page (Test2), everything works fine, but I want to be able to run it from sheet Test1 since that is where the data is being copied from and my goal is to have a button to run the script.

With setActiveSheet(Sheet sheet, Bool restoreSelection) - the restoreSelection set to true is supposed to ensure the most recent selection is selected again, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Test1');
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Test2');
  var r1 = s1.getRange('A7:A19');
  ss.setActiveSheet(s2, true);
  var activeCell = s2.getActiveCell();
r1.copyTo(activeCell,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
}
```

Comment: My experience suggests that is currently not possible.  It is interesting to note that if you switch pages each page returns to the cell that it was on during the last time in was visited so the information must be so where but it doesn't appears to be available to apps script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your goal to append something to Test2? In that case you can approach this easily by finding the lastRow using getLastRow() of Test2 and then appending it.

Comment: That should work great for what I am doing. Thanks.